# What should be the ideal Kafka "RequestMetrics.RemoteTimeMs" value for FetchConsumer specifically?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka 0.11.0 Documentation mentions the normal values for the MBean "RequestMetrics.RemoteTimeMs" as "non-zero for produce requests when ack=-1"

Link to official documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation.html#monitoring

[image]

Does this mean, for FetchConsumer(RequestMetrics.RemoteTimeMs.FetchConsumer) or any non-producer, the value should be **Zero(0ms)**? As ack configurations are not applicable for Consumer requests(non-producer requests).

Answer (score 0):

For consumer/follower fetch request, `RemoteTimeMs` is the time that the server needs to wait if there isn’t enough data to return to the consumer/follower. For consumer case, this will likely be 500ms (default of fetch.max.wait.ms).

See below JMX metrics. You can run the [jmx-monitoring-stack](https://github.com/confluentinc/jmx-monitoring-stacks) to see all these metrics with Prometheus and Grafana.
[image]